# wordpress error log: force_ssl_login is deprecated since version 4.4! Use force_ssl_admin() instead

Tags: wordpress, ssl, authentication, admin

I turned on debugging for my wordpress site,
and i started getting these errors in my error log.

> [25-Feb-2016 05:30:18 UTC] PHP Notice:  force_ssl_login is
>   **deprecated** since version 4.4! Use force_ssl_admin()
>   instead. in /home/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3573

is there function or filter that turns ssl login into ssl admin?

i have tried the the `wp-config.php`

```
define ('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true );
```

method, but it's not working.
my website is still slow with frequent error 500s happening.

any help would be appreciated getting this out of my error log.

Answer (score 0):

This is a plugin or your theme who's doing this the old way. Turn off each plugin one by one to see which is causing it. If you've found it ask the creator to update the plugin. Also try this for your theme if it's not a plugin.

Also you should update any plugins or theme anyway.